# Authenticate user without password once after verification

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I have a standard `LocalStrategy` Passport.js authentication strategy. During this, the `LocalStrategy` checks the password against the database using `bcrypt`, and authenticates the session. In case you need to see the code:

```
const LocalStrategy = passportLocal.Strategy;
const userStrategyHandler = async (username, password, done) => {
  const [ userFetchErr, user ] = await to(userService.findByEmail(username));

  // ...

    const authResult = await authService.comparePassword(password, user.password);

  // ...

  return done(null, user);
};

const userStrategy = new LocalStrategy(userStrategyHandler);
passport.use(userStrategy);
```

However, when they sign up, I send an email that verifies the user's account. When they click the link, it currently redirects them to the homepage. They are not logged in, which is not a great UX, but there's an opportunity before the redirect in the `/verify` route to potentially log the user in

Is there a way to authenticate the user on the server-side, without requiring calling the Passport `LocalStrategy`? That way I could log the user in the one time upon verification. After that, the user will authenticate using their password. Or is there another way to achieve that result?

Comment: don't you want to use passport authenticate at all?? I use `jsonwebtoken` and `bcryptjs` modules for authentication instead of LocalStrategy of Passport... If I want in several ways authenticate my users, I use passport

Comment: Hey Mohammad. No that's not the question - I'd like to authenticate once without a password once the user has clicked the authentication link. From that point onward, the user should log in using the local strategy.

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: No, I didn't figure it out, so I've let it be for now. They can just log in, there's a redirect after 5 seconds to the login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this situation, you should create a link like below based on `jwt` and send to use email:

```
https://website/verify#token=eyJpZCI6Nzk5OTEwNzc3NjMyMzI1NjU0LCJlbWFpbCI6Im0ueS5haG
```

this token should store in a new table that have two column, `token` and `status`, status first of all is `true` after click on the link in email, `/verify` route called ,and the status will be `false` and becomes invalid for the token, so if the token valid and status true you can redirect user to homepage, without passport you can do what you want
``

Comment: That's an interesting approach! So just to clarify: 1) when the account is created, set `status = false`, 2) when the verification link is clicked, set `status = true`, 3) upon that first authentication (determined by `status == true`), set `status = false`

Comment: I'll post an answer on how I solved this, which I think is simpler in this instance. I like this approach too!

Comment: no, when you want sent email to user, before sending email create a row in table with `status: true` and a `expire time(2 min)` for `jwt` created, after click on link or timeout you set `status :false`

Comment: Great answer. I've accepted my own because it doesn't require the extra `jwt` mechanism, but this is definitely a correct solution :)

Comment: Scrap the above comment, this answer is the secure way to do this

Answer (score 1):

<s>It was actually very easy to resolve this. I added another column (`isInitialVerification BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE`). Then, on the `/verify` route, I set `isIntialVerification` to true. In the Passport `LocalStrategy`, I simply checked for the column value and then reset it to false.</s>

Make sure you throw an error (i.e., return `done(err, ...)`) if you cannot update the `isInitialVerification` value back to false, to avoid the potential of permanent authentication - the worst case is they'll have to manually log in.

The above is incorrect. Anybody could send the request between the `isInitialVerification` and the next request, and be authenticated. See Mohammad's answer for a possible solution instead